# HAML: Font Awesome-Icons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

```
%nav
  = link_to "Registrieren", "/signup" do
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
  = link_to "Anmelden", "/login" do
    <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
```

What must I change for this to work?

The Debugger tells me: "NoMethodError"!

Comment: What error is coming up with the No Method Error ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
%nav
  = link_to "/signup" do
    Registrieren
    %i.fa.fa-arrow-right
  = link_to "/login" do
    Anmelden
    %i.fa.fa-arrow-right
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `i` elements are raw HTML, you can't render HTML within a file with a `.haml` extension.

Answer (score 0):

And, if you're using `font-awesome-rails` gem

```
%nav
  = link_to "/signup" do
    Registrieren
    = fa_icon("arrow-right")
  = link_to "/login" do
    Anmelden
    = fa_icon("arrow-right")
```